# Bootstrap modal not working on a mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this button that displays a bootstrap modal when it is clicked. The modal shows up well on my browser, but when I minimize my browser and try to click on the button, the button becomes unclickable.

What might be the problem?

```html
<button class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal'  data-target='#{$result['id']}'>
  Message
</button>";

<div class='modal fade' id='{$result['id']}' tabindex='-1' role='dialog'
     aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>  
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <p class='text-center'>
          <a href='login.php?location=$location' class='follow_btn_a'>
          You must login to send a message. Click to login
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-dismiss='modal'>
          Cancel
        </button>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: problem is probably js/jquery or css side... seems fine in html. You should try to "simplify" and post example on http://bootply.com

Comment: Working fine... http://www.bootply.com/KpXOMPDzK1       btw, why is there =>";<= at the end of your button line??

Comment: @Julo0sS When I resize that page, it says: 
"Bootstrap Editor use requires a larger screen resolution. Resize your browser, or use a device with a larger screen (desktop or laptop). You can preview at smaller widths (phone / tablet), but the editing capability is disabled." Does it mean my modal can only work on desktop?

Comment: I suggest not to use `' '` with your `html` attributes like I see here `id='something'` or  `type='button'` etc., instead use `type="button"` I mean with `" "` [double quotes]

Comment: @radioactive This does not mean that your modal can only work on desktop. This is just a "bootply" thing. Bootply asks larger resolutions. Just test your snippet out of bootply to check for the smaller resolutions modal and you'll see that it works fine too.